# Null safe packages throw error: "Cannot run with sound null safety"

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:hooks_riverpod
 - package:flutter_riverpod
 - package:riverpod
```

I don't understand, these packages shouldn't have this problem, they are null safe.

And when I run `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`
getting a bunch of errors starting with this one:

```
/D:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ri
verpod-0.12.4/lib/src/common.freezed.dart:121:4: Erro
r: Getter not found: 'nullable'.
```

Answer (score 0):

If these packages do not support null safety, you will have to stay on the old version of flutter or discard these dependencies until the developers update the dependencies, if null safety is supported try to make a migration https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Comment: But riverpod supports null safety already..

Comment: yes, I checked it right now, follow official instruction for migrate dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Update your packages to the versions that support null-safety.